# morph/morpheme analyis

Tags: morphology, morphemes, morphological-analysis

After analyzing many words morphologically I come across the following three words which I found hard to analyze:

linguistic

> morphs: lingu/ist/ic --> 3 morphs; Would 'lingu' be then a bound lexical morph?
>
> morphemes: [lingua]+[ist]+[ic] --> 3morphemes; Would 'lingua' be the root to use here?

literary

> morphs: literary  --> 1 morph
>
> morphemes: [literary] --> 1 morpheme?

has aroused

> morphs: has/arouse/d --> 3morphs
>
> morphemes: [arouse]+[present perfect] OR [have]+[3rd person]+[sg]+[arouse]+[past participle]
> Is there such a thing as a present perfect morpheme?

Comment: None of these are English words with English morphemes. They're borrowed, already formed, with centuries of derivation and inflection showing on their bones, from Latin and Greek. So English rules don't really apply well. There is a different set of morphemes that attach to classical roots than the set of morphemes that attach to native roots.

Comment: ahhh... okay, that explains why these words were so hard to analyze. Thanks for that hint! 'arise', however, is of OE origin, right?

Comment: The OED says that diachronically the derivation was linguist+ic=> linguistic. Not sure if we could argue the same derivation synchronically though.

Comment: What do you mean by "morphs"? What framework calls them that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *lingu-* part may well be analyzed as a bound root. It depends somewhat on the inclination of the analyst, but for many linguists the presence of the suffix *-ist* in *linguist*, where *-ist* is clearly carrying out its usual function of indicating a person specializing in some field of expertise, is more than enough evidence to show that the word *linguist* is morphologically complex.

More controversially, the presence of the *lingu-* morpheme without *-ist* in words like *lingual* and *sublingual* may be further evidence, though there the meaning 'tongue' is far more common than the meaning 'language', so that may be a different morpheme.

I see little evidence to suggest that the root in question is *lingua-*, since I don't know of any English words where the [a] shows up clearly. (The [a] in *lingual* comes from the suffix *-al*.) So I'd argue that the morpheme is just *lingu-*, and it's a bound root roughly meaning 'language', although as with many bound morphemes, it may enter into complex words whose meanings can't be composed purely from their parts (i.e. morphological idioms).

Comment: At first I was thinking about regarding 'lingu-' as a bound rood as well. However, then I thought of the compound "lingua franca" where 'lingua' occurs as a free lexical content word and thus was wondering if I could choose 'lingua' as a morpheme here...

Answer (score 0):

"Lingua franca" is a borrowed phrase from (Medieval) Latin, and best analyzed as only tangentially related to the "lingu-" morpheme that participates in the rest of English morphology.